# Using sagemath: how do I fix this error TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python, vector, sage

Basically I have a list of vectors. I want to plot a graph but there are too many vectors so adding them up one by one takes too long. So, I want to make a command that adds up the vectors in my list while the vector's starting points are the vectors added up before that one (sounds confusing, I know).

Here is what I get:

```
data=[[24,333],[7,260],[4,190],[6,75],[3,145],[3,270],[4,51],[4,336],[7,160],[7,60],[4,185],[4,275],[3,330],[4,65],[13,187],[8,54],[8,181],[5,70]]
listofvectors=[vector([eachelement[0]*sin(eachelement[1]*pi/180),eachelement[0]*cos(eachelement[1]*pi/180)]) for eachelement in data]
temporarylist = [vector([0,0])]+listofvectors
startpoint=[sum(temporarylist[:i+1]) for i in list(IntegerRange(len(temporarylist)))]
```

```
c446a9ff-1351-496c-b175-56d5f12db2f7︡ {"stderr":"Error in lines 1-1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/projects/722ebd7e-9c91-47a9-af93-ad326a20df5d/.sagemathcloud/sage_server.py\", line 879, in execute
    exec compile(block+'\\n', '', 'single') in namespace, locals
  File "", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
"}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged C++ and R?

Comment: those were the suggested tags

Comment: If your question doesn't relate to those languages, don't tag them as such.

Comment: In regards to your question, did you make a variable called `list` earlier in your code?

Comment: im sorry im new to all this

Comment: i made a list called listofvectors, then temporarylist which is nothing but listofvectors but with starting point 0,0

Comment: You're going to have to post some more code. Please make up an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem you're having, so we can reproduce it. Otherwise, it's just guessing...

Comment: What is `IntegerRange`?

Comment: should i show my whole work? its not that much

Comment: list(IntegerRange(len(temporarylist)))  is supposed to give a list of consecuitve integers starting from 0

Comment: If someone else can run it independently and get the same results, then yes please post it. I know what that call is supposed to do, I'm just asking what `IntegerRange` is.

Comment: edited my post ehmm.. im not quite sure sir . my teacher told me to use that

Comment: so can anyone help me? it is really important

Answer (score 1):

The key is that this is

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

This indicates you have taken a object `list` and then used `list(stuff)`, the Python syntax for "calling a function" (think like f(x) in math).  In this case, it is pretty clear (as @MattDMo points out) that you must have actually called something `list` earlier in your code.   Otherwise you would get something like

```
sage: list(IntegerRange(5))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

as desired.  Search through your worksheet for this - perhaps restart your worksheet and then do *just* this cell?